# What is best way to configure logging in spring integration based projects?

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-integration

I am creating a framework based on spring integration. I want to configure logging that can be applied to all spring integration configurations. In the log, I want to log time, channel name, Message body+ headers, and last endpoint details.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest way is to enable debug logging on a `org.springframework.integration` category and all the components from Spring Integration will log some info about their behavior.

Another one is to use a Wire-Tap pattern: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-wiretap. This one can be configured globally with a pattern(s) on channels you'd like to wire-tap. The subscriber for that tapping channel could be simply a `org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler`, which is also described in that doc.

About endpoints info, I'd suggest to look into a Message History pattern, which just place into a special message header the path this message has traveled so far: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#message-history

Therefore a combination of the wire-tap and message history with a logging channel adapter in the end should meet your requirements.